# Regex Need Help - Two Functions

Tags: regex

I know little to nothing when it comes to RegEx and am having some trouble trying to pull information using it. I have a VBS Script that outputs the following information and what I need is a RegEx Function to pull two lines out.

Script output:

2012-02-19T00:00:00

242

I need one function to grab "2012-02-19T00:00:00" and another one to grab "242". If needed, I can format the output of the script to make things easier.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: If the script only outputs two lines, why do you need a regex to do this? Read the first line for the date, and the second for the `242`.

Comment: Are these two going to be in single lines? And is the number on the second line is always going to be of 3 digits like `242`? And what have to tried so far and did not work? Post your code.

Comment: The reason for the RegEx is because I am using another application (LabTech) to run the vbs script on each of our managed machines. It stores the shell results in a %shellresult% variable that I'm able to read with their RegEx Script functions. Instead of having the vbs script output the results to two separate .txt files to read from, I though it might be easier to just read the shell results directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For text strings like `2012-02-19T00:00:00`, the following RegEx will do:

```
^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$
```

For the second string of 3 digit number, the following will do, however if your string will contain more digits just change `{3}` to whatever you need.

```
^\d{3}$
```

I am assuming here that the strings will be in its own line.

Comment: This would only validate a string, but won't give you that format from a chunk of text. Replacing `^` with `(` and `$` with `)` would capture the values from anywhere in the script output. The second function would need an additional check for whitespace (`\s`) though, to prevent the year being matched as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. The code above worked perfectly. I just had to remove the '$' from the top string and the '^' from the bottom one. I am now getting the output as expected and requested.